# Electron count of complexes

Tags: coordination-compounds

For counting the electrons of the complex (RO)3W≡CMe, the book considers three RO- groups that donate a total of 10 electrons and it regards ≡CMe as [carbyne]- group in the ionic model and has a total of 16 electrons.

What confuses me is that:

1. The RO- group used to consider a 4 electron donor because they can form a sigma bond with metal and they can also donate 2 lone pair electrons to the metal (as a pi-donor), so they can donate overall 4 electrons. However, this seems not to be the case. I wonder whether it's because that 10=4+4+2, which means that only 2 RO- act as pi-donor and the other is sigma-donor only?
2. I used to consider M≡CR as M(III) and CR(-3) in the ionic model considering the electronegativity. I don't understand why carbyne can be regarded as the group with only 1 negative charge. Nevertheless, when I consider M(III) and CR(-3) and count the total electrons, it also turns out to be 16e. Does that mean the two ways are both available?